# Keyboard Input Assistance

Tags: python, pygame

I want the code to be so that if I press a certain key,the flashlight color

```
pygame.draw.ellipse(gameDisplay, yellow,[375+lead_x,-43+lead_y,105,led])
```

becomes brighter,such as light yellow.Please assist.Here is the full code.

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
white = (34,34,34)
black=(0,0,0)
red=(255,0,0)
led=45
silver=(110,108,108)
yellow=(193,206,104)
yellow2=(213,230,100)
gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))
pygame.display.set_caption('Slither')

gameExit=False

myfont = pygame.font.SysFont("monospace", 15)
lead_x = 300
lead_y = 300
background_color=black
while not gameExit:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            gameExit = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                lead_x -= 10
                print("LEFT")

            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                lead_x +=10
                print("RIGHT")
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                 lead_y -=10
                 print("UP")
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                 lead_y +=10
                 print("DOWN")
            if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                gameDisplay.fill(red)
                led +=10
            if led == 95:
                background_color=red
                print("YOU FOUND ME.NOW YOU WILL D I E")
                background_color=red

    gameDisplay.fill(background_color)
    pygame.draw.ellipse(gameDisplay, black,[-295+300,-54+300,75,100])
    pygame.draw.ellipse(gameDisplay, red,[-285+300,-35+300,20,34])
    pygame.draw.ellipse(gameDisplay, red,[-255+300,-35+300,20,34])
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, silver,[470+lead_x,-35+lead_y,75,30])
    pygame.draw.ellipse(gameDisplay, yellow,[375+lead_x,-43+lead_y,105,led])


    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that **PyGame supports [RGBA color values](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/color.html#pygame.Color)** (*r*ed, *g*reen, *b*lue and *a*lpha value of a Color), but unfortunately **PyGames draw functions don´t draw transparently** (according to the [domcumanetaion](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html)).

To avoid this problem you could

1. **Create new surface**
2. **Change the alpha value** for it using [`.set_alpha()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.set_alpha)
3. **Draw your "flashlight" ellipse** onto the new surface
4. **Blit this surface onto the main screen** surface by calling the [.blit()](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit) method which supports alpha transparency

Here is the updated program:

```
# ... your code

alpha = 0

while not gameExit:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            gameExit = True

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            #...  your original code 

            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
               #change alpha value
               alpha += 10

    gameDisplay.fill(background_color)

    pygame.draw.ellipse(gameDisplay, black,[-295+300,-54+300,75,100])
    pygame.draw.ellipse(gameDisplay, red,[-285+300,-35+300,20,34])
    pygame.draw.ellipse(gameDisplay, red,[-255+300,-35+300,20,34])


    alphaSurface = pygame.Surface((105,led)) # 1.

    alphaSurface.set_alpha(alpha) # 2.
    alphaSurface.fill(background_color)

    pygame.draw.ellipse(alphaSurface, yellow,[0,0,105,led]) # 3.
    gameDisplay.blit(alphaSurface, (375+lead_x,-43+lead_y)) # 4.


    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, silver,[470+lead_x,-35+lead_y,75,30])

    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Please note that we need to change the background color and the size of the `alphaSurface` surface **each iteration** of the main loop to get the expected result and this might slow down our game.

You could also consider using the `pygame.HWSURFACE` flag to **create a hardware-accelerated surface**.See the [PyGame documentation about surfaces](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) for more information.